# What do you get when you cut a disk out of a Klein Bottle?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, klein-bottle

I heard that you can obtain a real projective plane by gluing a disk to a Mobius band. But then I thought: if you cut a disk out of a Klein bottle (1 face, 0 edges) you'd get a shape with 1 face and 1 edges. This sounds a lot like a mobius band, but clearly isn't because that would mean reinserting the disk would yield a Klein bottle, **not** the aforementioned projective plane. What do you get instead?

Comment: To get a cylinder from a torus, you have to cut a circle without interior - a circle not contractile to a point. Same for a Klein bottle and a Möbius band. I don’t think you get “anything” cutting a disk out of a Klein bottle, other than ensuring you can embed the space in three dimensions.

Comment: I don't want to cut a ring around the klein bottle (like turning a torus into a cylinder), that wouldn't physically remove a disk. If you cut a ring around a klein bottle it would also make a cylinder.

Comment: I would make a picture with the square representation of the Klein bottle with opposite edges identified. A disc is a rectangle in the middle, that should be identifiable.

Answer (score 1):

A Klein bottle with a small disk removed is topologically the result of taking two Möbius bands and gluing an interval on the boundary of one to an interval on the boundary of the other. It's easy enough to make a paper model that an image seems superfluous.